# Everything hangs on installing wine

Tags: system, apt, wine

I have tried to install wine (using `apt-get install wine`) up today.
However, after working a bit, the whole desktop decided to hang and I couldn't move the mouse.

IIRC, it was showing up "processing triggers for libc6" when that happened. I needed to force shutdown and restart elementary OS again and I did not have issue after then, but Wine was not installed and for that reason i could not start it.

But now when I am trying to do anything with *apt-get* it says :

> E: dpkg a été interrompu. Il est nécessaire d'utiliser « sudo dpkg --configure -a » pour corriger le problème.

Which in english should mean :

> E: dpkg was stopped. You need to use "sudo dpkg --configure -a" to fix this problem.

However, when I am doing so, it tries to end up the Wine installation again and so crashes again. 
It requires me to use this command even if I try uninstalling Wine, so now I cannot use `apt-get` (and probably nothing dpkg-related).

I doubt this issue is related to Wine, but because of some download corruption. However I cannot manage to cancel anything I've done.

Probably marking the wine package as not installed would be a very bad workaround but it would work. Is there any way to do this?

**Edit:**

It probably could be a kernel panic as well, however, nothing showed up on the screen - It just decided to hang and I couldn't even move the cursor. I cannot find anything about a kernel crash in `/var/crash`. Attempting switching TTYs with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> didn't work neither.

Comment: Did you make sure to add the PPA first? It's _really_ recommended to do that first. https://www.winehq.org/download/ubuntu

Comment: Either way, I cannot do anything dpkg-related, else I am making the whole desktop hang. I believe the download was corrupt. But as I said, I'd need a way to fix up the dpkg problem before trying to install it again.

Comment: You should be able to remove the package with `apt-get remove` and then `apt-get autoremove` the dependencies that are no longer required. If that does not work, you can delete the contents of `/var/lib/dpkg/updates` to force it to download them again.

Answer (score 1):

If faced such problem some time ago, when I got a `libc` update in a machine with nVidia proprietary driver install, It hanged with blinking leds.

The solution was:

1. Reboot and Press <kbd>Shift</kbd> to show grub menu
2. Select recovery mode.
3. Run a file system check
4. Enable network
5. Drop to shell
6. Continue installation there

   ```
   dpkg --configure -a
   ```

   and install Wine (if previous command didn't)

   ```
   apt-get install wine
   ```
7. `reboot`

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer (and sorry for the extremely long delay). Since I switched to a SSD and installed a fresh Arch setup on this laptop I now don't encounter such trouble anymore. The issue is that the "dpkg --configure -a" command caused the kernel panic.